# Terminal command to control Night Shift in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra, beta

Does anyone know of a Terminal command to control Night Shift in the 10.12.4 beta? I've been looking through plist files but can't find anything related to night shift.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and didn't have any luck, so I threw together some code for a simple command line tool to control the feature. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jenghis/nshift/releases).

It works by making calls to the `CoreBrightness` private framework. Specifically, it creates an instance of `CBBlueLightClient` and calls the instance methods `setStrength:commit:` and `setEnabled:`.

Usage is `nshift strength` where strength is a value from 0 to 100. A higher value shifts the color temperature of the display to more warm. A value of 0 disables Night Shift altogether.

Comment: Hi. Can we override the default temperature max/min? Flux can get really yellow orangey while I find that MacOS NightShift is still too white/bright for late night work.

Answer (score 3):

### 2022 Answer

Try https://github.com/smudge/nightlight, "A CLI for configuring 'Night Shift' on macOS"

Alfred workflow that uses it: https://github.com/shmulvad/alfred-nightshift/

Working for me on macOS Ventura 13.0.1